# 365 office runtime 1004 debuging

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

When is creating the tableData
"run time error 1004 vba "

Im using 365 office and the code was working perfecty in excel 2013, now it gives me an error in the row of tableData as it is setting the range

```
Sub SendEmails(ByVal eMailType As String, ByVal SendEmailTo As String, ByVal SendEmailToCC As String)
    Dim ws_email_templates As Worksheet
    Dim Email_Send_From, Email_Subject, Email_Body1, Email_Body2 As String
    Dim emailTypeRow As Long
    Dim tableData As Range

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    Set ws_email_templates = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("email_templates")
    Set tables = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tranlsate_Table")
    emailTypeRow = ws_email_templates.Range("A1:I1").Find(eMailType).Column



    GetEmailBody1 = ws_email_templates.Cells(4, emailTypeRow)
    GetEmailBody2 = ws_email_templates.Cells(5, emailTypeRow)
    GetEmailPriority = ws_email_templates.Cells(6, emailTypeRow)

    Email_Send_From = ws_email_templates.Cells(2, emailTypeRow)
    Email_Subject = ws_email_templates.Cells(3, emailTypeRow)

    If Right(eMailType, 18) = "contractEnd_noData" Or Right(eMailType, 17) = "creditTime_noData" Then
        Email_Body = GetEmailBody1
    Else
        tabelaDataColumn = tables.Range("A1:Z1").Find(eMailType).Column
        tabelaDataLastRow = tables.Cells(1000, tabelaDataColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        'Set tableData = tables.Range("V2:Z3")

        **'error
        Set tableData = tables.Range(Cells(2, tabelaDataColumn), Cells(tabelaDataLastRow, tabelaDataColumn + 4))**

        Email_Body = GetEmailBody1 & RangetoHTML(tableData) & GetEmailBody2
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Set tableData = tables.Range(Cells(2, tabelaDataColumn), Cells(tabelaDataLastRow, tabelaDataColumn + 4))
> ```

That code will work perfectly fine... as long as `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tranlsate_Table")` (with that typo) is the `ActiveSheet`.

If the `tables` worksheet isn't active, then the unqualified `Cells` member calls are going against `Global`, and forwarded to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is.

And since a `Range` knows what sheet it's in (through its `Parent` property), then...

```
Sheet1.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1), Sheet2.Cells(10, 10))
```

...isn't something Excel can resolve :)

Just qualify the `Cells` member calls with the `Worksheet` object you mean to work with.

```
Set tableData = tables.Range(tables.Cells(2, tabelaDataColumn), tables.Cells(tabelaDataLastRow, tabelaDataColumn + 4))
```

Note that Rubberduck (an open-source VBE add-in project I manage) can help you locate all such [implicit ActiveSheet references](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) in your code.